# Set property of another bean after action method is invoked

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, mojarra

Mojarra 2.2

I have two beans`.

```
public class MyBean1{

    private String myProperty1;
    //GET, SET, CTOR

    public void doAction(){
         //assign something to myProperty1
    }
}

public class MyBean2{

    private String myProperty2;
    //GET, SET, CTOR
}
```

Now, I need to assign the value of the property `MyBean1::myProperty1` to `MyBean2::myProperty2` after the `doAction()` method invocation by clicking a button:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{myBean1.doAction}">
     <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{myBean2.myProperty2}"
                                   value="#{myBean1.myProperty1}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

But it doesn't work. And I figured out that it doesn't work due to the following reason:

Clicking a button causes `ActionEvent` to be broadcasted. It performs by this method (`javax.faces.component.UICommand`):

```
public void broadcast(FacesEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {

    super.broadcast(event); //1       <-------------------- HERE

    if (event instanceof ActionEvent) {
        FacesContext context = getFacesContext();


        MethodBinding mb = getActionListener();
        if (mb != null) {
            mb.invoke(context, new Object[] { event });
        }


        ActionListener listener =
        context.getApplication().getActionListener();
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.processAction((ActionEvent) event);
        }
    }
}
```

I've noticed that the `ActionEvent` broadcasting by clickng the button is being handled by two listeners and one that comes from  `super.broadcast(event)` invokation at `//1` is `com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.SetPropertyActionListenerHandler.SetPropertyListener`.

The handling is performed ***before*** invokation of the action method.

Of course, I can embed the action method invokation into the `MyBean1:getMyProperty1()` getter, so the `myProperty1` field will be properly intialized, but it seems quite wierd to me. What is the right way to achieve that?

Comment: The value of `myBean2.myProperty2` is likely to be unavailable at the moment the button is clicked. There could be a scoped-related problem or the value of that property is not set or initialized explicitly before the button is clicked.

Comment: @Tiny Sorry, it was a typo. Checked

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener